# Load resources without displaying the "loading" spinner

Tags: javascript, html

I'm loading a large Javascript file asynchronously as part of a long form. The script is used only at the end of the form. However, when I open the form, my browser (Chrome and Firefox) displays the "loading" spinner when the script is loading, even though it isn't needed yet. Is it possible to prevent the browser from displaying the spinner when loading a resource? (don't have to be a script)

If a solution is available, I know it'll be different for each browser. I only care about the latest version of Chrome, FF, and IE.

Comment: The loading spinner is not a default behavior when asynchronously loading something; the script used to load the resource is probably at fault here. If you could edit your post to include it, we could more easily help you

Comment: You're right, the script is loading other scripts synchronously. If you make that an answer, I'll mark it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The loading spinner is not a default behavior when asynchronously loading something; the script used to load the resource is probably at fault here. If you could edit your post to include it, we could more easily help you

Comment: This is not an answer and should not be posted as such.  I don't understand why this got any upvotes.  It's a comment - correct, yes - but a only comment.

Comment: See the comments under the OP. In fairness, however, you're right in that it's not a direct answer, but it helped him solve his problem